# IE11 Box-shadow spread and border-radius

Tags: html, css

I see a rendering issue in IE11 when it comes to multiple box-shadows on an element with rounded border. In this use case i've tried not to use borders but only box-shadows to create some sharp outlines for a button.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000000 inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
```

This CSS should create a box with a black outline and white inline, like this:

[image]

So far so good. When i also add some border-radius, the result in Firefox and Chrome looks pretty much like this:

[image]

This was the desired effect. But IE (11) somehow renders this pretty weird:

[image]

The border radius seems to be off. **Here is a jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ebjWB/1/**

Does anybody have an idea what I can do against this blurred border or will i have to use borders or shadows with actual size?

Comment: Why are you using `inset` and what's wrong with borders?

Comment: Very good question @Paulie_D I gues i wanted the element size calucalated without the box-shadow. But your comment does answer the question: http://jsfiddle.net/ebjWB/2/ this looks better in IE11. Thank you very much. May you post an answer?

Comment: Box-shadow doesn't add to the size (AFAIK).

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake. I ment I have to have it in mind, when i place elements next to each other, like in the link in my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `box-shadow` does not add additional dimension to the element (AFAIK) you can just remove the `inset` property.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebjWB/2/)

```
a
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 0 0 0 2px #000000  ;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer, when the 5 minutes are over. Thank you very much. I still think IE11 should not render the box-shadow like this or am i missing a point here?

Answer (score 1):

You could try mixing `border` with `box-shadow`. I can't guarantee it works in every browser, but it does fix the corners in IE11. (Please note I have reduced the padding to compensate for the border)

```
a {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This work in fact, thank you! But I was interested in this certain IE behaviour. Good addition anyways.